# check if key variable is equal to button

Tags: autohotkey

i wanna click a random button 50 times from a list unless it is `1` only click it once, its always going to the else even if key is `1`

```
!F2::
    breakvar = 1
return

!F1::
    loop                                                    
    {
        Random, var, 1,7
        keyList = {1},{2},{3},{w},{a},{s},{d}
        StringSplit, KeyAry, KeyList, `,,%A_Space%
        key := KeyAry%var%
        loop 50
        {
            ; i've tryied:
              ;(%key% = "1")
              ;(key = 1)
              ;(key = {1})
            ; but with out success

            if (key = "1")
            {
                Send, %key%
                break
            }
            else
            {
                Send, %key%
                Sleep, 100
            }
        }
    if breakvar = 1
        break
}
breakvar = 0
return
```

also is there a better way to achieve what i am trying to do?

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main mistake was that you indeed didn't manage to get the if statement corrent. The right one would've been `if (key = "{1}")`.
But really, I don't know why you even had the `{ }`, it's a common mistake I see from nearly every beginner, I wonder where it comes from.
You're only supposed to use `{ }` for escaping or if the special notation is needed for something such as `{space}`. Read more from the [documentation](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm).

Here's a cleaned up script with all other weirdness removed as well:

```
KeyList := StrSplit("1,2,3,{space},+1,w,", ",") ; +1 is shift + 1 (whatever key that will produce in your keyboard layout)

!F2::BreakVar := true

!F1::
    loop
    {
        Random, index, 1, 7
        key := KeyList[index]
        loop 2
        {
            SendInput, % key
            if (key = "1")
                break
            Sleep, 100
        }

        if (BreakVar)
            break
    }

BreakVar := false
return
```

To be totally correct, I should say that you shouldn't loop under hotkeys and should use a [timer](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetTimer.htm) instead, but I wont add that in to confuse you. This should be fine as well, if you have problems with hotkeys after this, you can look into a timer approach yourself or ask help here.

Comment: what would the timer approach be like? 
check if the break variable has been changed every second?
and ho is it any better?

Comment: No, you wouldn't have any break variable. You'd just start and stop the timer as you see fit. And it would be better because you wouldn't loop in the hotkey thread, and would keep the hotkey thread empty and ready. But with this script you probably shouldn't have any trouble. Just some food for future thought.